# Почему функция min быстрее среза с функцией sorted

Tags: python, время

Хотел проверить теорию, что будет быстрее отсортировать список и вывести число минимальное или отсортировать список и вывести индекс 0, в итоге функции оказались быстрее. (возможно я плохо код написал)

```
import time


def check_time_with_index():
    start = time.time()
    q = sorted(numbers)[0]
    return time.time() - start


def check_time_with_min_function():
    start = time.time()
    q = sorted(min(numbers))
    return time.time() - start


numbers = [[0 for i in range(10)] for j in range(1_000_000)]

print(check_time_with_index())
print(check_time_with_min_function())

# примерное время выполнения кода
# время выполнения кода 0.05109453201293945 функцией sorted через индекс
# время выполнения кода 0.028855562210083008 функцией sorted через min()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: На 11-12 строке, смотря что возращать, будет довольно сильно отличатся время, хочу узнать почему отсортированный список кортежей и вызванной функцией min, быстрее работает, чем отсортированный список кортежей и выводом нулевого индекса ( урезал код, так он хотя бы читается)

Comment: 1 у вас каждый раз генерится разный набор чисел. так не сравнивают. 2 min - простая операция, которую можно выполнить за один проход, сортировка же куда сложнее.

Comment: Сортировка работает за `O(nlogn)`, а поиск минимума за `O(n)`.

К примеру при `n = 1_000_000`, сортировка сделает примерно `14_000_000` операций, а минимум найдётся за `1_000_000`

Comment: изменил код, теперь все числа являются нулями, так, генерация не влияет, на то что числа могут быть разными

Comment: `q = sorted(numbers)[0]`  и `q = sorted(min(numbers))` делают не одно и то же. первый код выдает минимальный список, а второй - сортирует минимальный список

Comment: `q = sorted(min(numbers))` по сути у вас работает сортировка из одного минимального значения. Правильно нужно написать так: `q = min(sorted(numbers))`